# Cannot start container on docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Once I removed `tiger` machine from the config file.

Everything will go well. But I don't get what wrong with the tiger.

Each machine share with the same `image`

When I ran `docker-compose up`, I got

> Cannot start container 38c203136f645a62451fbbc19bcdae0b1c31a45495e3e02588bc8182397f0e2e: [8] System error: open /proc/self/fd: no such file or directory

### - docker-compose 1.2.0

```
jetstar:
  mem_limit: 512m
  image: newbike/firefox-standalone
  volumes:
  - "./:/project-bird"
  ports:
  - 5902
peach:
  mem_limit: 512m
  image: newbike/firefox-standalone
  volumes:
  - "./:/project-bird"
  ports:
  - 5903
scoot:
  mem_limit: 512m
  image: newbike/firefox-standalone
  volumes:
  - "./:/project-bird"
  ports:
  - 5904
tiger:
  mem_limit: 512m
  image: newbike/firefox-standalone
  volumes:
  - "./:/project-bird"
  ports:
  - 5905
vanilla:
  mem_limit: 512m
  image: newbike/firefox-standalone
  volumes:
  - "./:/project-bird"
  ports:
  - 5906
```

Comment: When you try run all container manually, the problem keep to occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are `38c203136f645a62451fbbc19bcdae0b1c31a45495e3e02588bc8182397f0e2e` is cached somewhere and need to be clean. When I face such issues, I just run `docker rm <sha>`.